# Conditional subdir-objects

Tags: build, gnu, autotools, automake

I have option `subdir-objects` set in `configure.ac`:

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects])
```

Is there any possibility to conditionally disable it in particular Makefiles (`Makefile.am`)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [list of automake options](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#List-of-Automake-options), no. What you can do instead is remove `subdir-objects` from the call to `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` and add it to the `Makefile.am` files where you actually want it. You do that by putting the line `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects` at the top of any relevant `Makefile.am`. (There's no `no-subdir-objects` option, apparently.)

Comment: This worked better for me than adding `[subdir-objects]` to AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE because I have included modules that use subdirs. By using this option I don't need to modify every top-level `configure.ac` file.